# I have a bash script for deploying my app to my production server, how can I use GitHub to automate when someone pushes to master?

Tags: github

The script is in `./bin/deploy.sh` and uses an SSH key to connect to the server.

I have a script in `package.json` called `npm run deploy:prod` which runs this bash script.

What do I need to get GitHub to run this script automatically when someone pushes or merges a PR to master?

Here is my `deploy.sh` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

. $HOME/.bashrc
. .env
. .env.local

args=(-azvP --delete --exclude=node_modules --exclude=.idea --exclude=.git)
hosts=($HOST_DOMAIN) # tornado lightning thunder tundra jefferson
dry=() #add --dry-run to enable testing
user=$HOST_USER
name=$HOST_PATH
project=$HOST_PROJECT

for host in "${hosts[@]}"
do
  echo ""
  date
  echo "---------------------"
  echo "syncing ${host}"
  echo "---------------------"
  rsync ${dry[@]} ${args[@]} ./ ${user}@${host}:www/${name}/${project}
  ssh -t ${user}@${host} \$HOME/www/${name}/${project}/bin/post-deploy.sh
done

version=$(jq -r .version package.json)
say "$HOST_PROJECT is live!"
exit
```

Here is my `post-deploy.sh` script that gets executed on the server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd "$(dirname "$0")/.."
. $HOME/.bashrc
. .env
. .env.local

host=$HOST_DOMAIN
name=$HOST_PATH
project=$HOST_PROJECT

echo "current name: $name"

cd $HOME/www/${name}/${project}
nvm install v18
node -v
npm -v
npm i

sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart ${META_SERVICE}
```

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions

Comment: which one satisfies my requirements?